# Java Script drop down options controlled by another drop down

Tags: javascript, html, select, drop-down-menu

I am extremely new to JavaScript. I am trying to control the options inside one listbox (called Aggregator) using the selected value of another (called Product). Below is the code I have written so far.

Now when I load the HTML page the code I have written to control the text boxes (using txt, txt2, txt3) does not work either now.

**Javascript**

```
function pGo() {

            var x = document.getElementById("Product").value;
            var txt = "";
            var txt2 = "";
            var txt3 = "";
            var list = document.getElementById("Aggregator");
            var aggrs = new Array();
            aggrs[0] = "h";
            aggrs[1] = "e";
            aggrs[2] = "l";
            aggrs[3] = "l";
            aggrs[4] = "l";
            aggrs[5] = "o";
            aggrs[6] = "o";
            var length = aggrs.length;
            var element = null;

            if (x == "HII") {
                txt = "Full ";
                txt2 = "/";
                txt3 = "/";
                for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)){
                element = aggrs[i]
                var opt = document.createElement("option");
                opt.innerText = element;
                opt.setAttribute(element, 'newvalue');
                list.appendChild(opt);
                }
            }
            else if (x == "DLG"){
                txt = "Full";
                txt2 = "/T";
                txt3 = "/responses/";
                for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++)){
                element = aggrs[i]
                var opt = document.createElement("option");
                opt.innerText = element;
                opt.setAttribute(element, 'newvalue');
                list.appendChild(opt);
                }
            }
            else if (x == "TBB"){
                txt = "Full ";
                txt2 = "/Trams";
                txt3 = "/respo";
                for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++)){
                element = aggrs[i]
                var opt = document.createElement("option");
                opt.innerText = element;
                opt.setAttribute(element, 'newvalue');
                list.appendChild(opt);
                }
                element = aggrs[6]
                var opt = document.createElement("option");
                opt.innerText = element;
                opt.setAttribute(element, 'newvalue');
                list.appendChild(opt);
            }               
            form.elements.calcType.value = txt;
            form.elements.transform.value = txt2;
            form.elements.calcResponse.value = txt3;
            }
```

**HTML**

```
product 
        <select id="Product" onchange = "pGo()">
            <option>HII</option>
            <option>DLG</option>
            <option>TBB</option>
        </select><div>
        <script type = "text/javascript">
aggregator      
        <select name = "Aggregator">
        </select><br/><br/>
```

*Other text boxes emitted*

I need the Aggregator to display certain values from the aggrs list depending on the value selected in the Product select:

HII : [0,1,2,3,4,5]

DLG : [0,1]

TBB : [0,1,6]

Comment: You might want to check out http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for general help on writing higher quality JS.

Comment: jQuery would make doing this sort of thing infinately easier.

Comment: thank you, will look into jQuery solutions tonight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, there are a LOT of syntax errors in your code.  I have added comments where I made those changes.

There was no id element "Aggregator" so I changed your markup:

```
product
<select id="Product" onchange="pGo();">
    <option>Pick one</option>
    <option>HII</option>
    <option>DLG</option>
    <option>TBB</option>
</select>
<div>aggregator
    <select id="Aggregator" name="Aggregator"></select>
    <br/>
    <br/>
</div>
```

You had a lot of duplicate code (still is some) and other issues (see comments)

```
// function to remove duplicate code
function addOptions(list, aggrs, limit) {
    var i = 0;
    // fix issue where option list did not empty on new select
    for (; i < list.length; i++) {
        list.remove(i);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < limit; i++) { // fix extra ")"
        var opt = document.createElement("option");
        element = aggrs[i]; //missing semicolon
        opt.text = element;  // use standard form not innerHtml
        opt.value = element;  // you had no value
        opt.setAttribute(element, 'newvalue');
        list.appendChild(opt);
    }
}

function pGo() {
    var x = document.getElementById("Product").value;
    var txt = "";
    var txt2 = "";
    var txt3 = "";
    var list = document.getElementById("Aggregator");
    var aggrs = ["h", "e", "l", "l", "l", "o", "o"]; //simpler array
    var length = aggrs.length;
    var element = null;
    if (x == "HII") {
        txt = "Full ";
        txt2 = "/";
        txt3 = "/";
        addOptions(list, aggrs, 5);

    } else if (x == "DLG") {
        txt = "Full";
        txt2 = "/T";
        txt3 = "/responses/";
        addOptions(list, aggrs, 1);
    } else if (x == "TBB") {
        txt = "Full ";
        txt2 = "/Trams";
        txt3 = "/respo";
        addOptions(list, aggrs, 1);
        // strange additional option added
        var oneAggr = [];
        oneAggr[0] = aggrs[6];
        addOptions(list, oneAggr, 1);
    }
    //  form.elements.calcType.value = txt;  // commented out due to not existing
    //  form.elements.transform.value = txt2;
    //  form.elements.calcResponse.value = txt3;
}
```

This is NOT really pretty (OK it is somewhat strange the options you set) even yet but at least it should work.

Sample to work with: http://jsfiddle.net/Qc4yD/

Comment: Thank you..  really helpful!! I had picked out code from many different sources so thanks for bringing it all together

Comment: Hi. I have been using this code for the last couple of weeks, and it works great! I want to add an extra default option into the Aggregator drop down, eg. "Pick one" so that when a new product is selected, it does not look like one of the options has been selected for you. I have added it into the aggr Array, and now it does not work. I was wondering if you could clarify why it is breaking, as adding an extra value to the array should not change anything? Thank you again for your answer

Comment: @a.hrdie - please create and post a new question with a reference link to this one to recieve an answer for your new question. I think I have a "better" answer somewhere in my list of things I can post. - if you want, post a link to it from a comment here for easy reference.

Comment: I will write a new question today, but I found what the problem was. In my aggr declaration I added a hyphen instead of a space "pick-one" and it was added successfully. I also found that using `list.innerHTML = '';` to clear the list in the addOptions() function works better than using the for-each loop as the indices of the drop down values changes each time one is removed. Will link to new question tonight

Answer (score 1):

Don't go learning jQuery if you're having trouble with basic JavaScript. You'll have worse problems with jQuery.

For a start, you're asking for the ID "Aggregator":

`var list = document.getElementById("Aggregator");`

when you don't have an object with the ID "Aggregator":

`<select name = "Aggregator"></select>`